# Oracle Query - Data changes during query execution

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query that essentially sums a number column, and this query can take a very long time to execute. I'm curious what the result of the query will be if rows are deleted or added during execution of the query.

The answer depends on how Oracle executes queries. Does it query a snapshot of the DB at the point of execution of the query, or does it account for live data changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the query works on a snapshot of the data at the time it started - "statement-level read consistency".

The long answer is in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#i13945).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and direct answer!